# how to take an input and put it in a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I take an input and append it as a list in a dictionary. So far I've tried:

```
fruits = {}
add_fruit = dict((input('Enter fruit follow by prices:').split(','' ') for i in range(x)))
    fruits.update(add_fruit)
    print(f'Current stock: {fruits}')
```

however this returns the values as a string instead of a list:

```
{'apple':'1 2 3'}
```

but I want it to return:

```
{'apple': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: What is `x`? What is `fruits`? What is your input?

Comment: the input is the fruit followed by the prices split between (,). for example: apple, 1 2 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your input, you can do like following; but you have to slightly modify to restrict number of prices to `x`.

```
inp = input('Enter fruit follow by prices: ').split(', ')
fruits = {inp[0]: inp[1].split()}
```

Comment: right but that doesn't append it to the fruit dictionary, instead it replaces it, i need it to add it to the dictionary

Comment: @sunnymuffinz, `fruits.update({inp[0]: inp[1].split()})`. You already know how to update. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the idea of what you trying to do in the code. but I looked at your example and I did like this

```
 fruit_name = input('Enter a fruit name:')
 fruit_price = int(input('Enter a fruit price you input early:'))
 test = [int(i) for i in str(fruit_price)]
 dictionaryy = {}
 dictionaryy[fruit_name]=test
 print(dictionaryy)
```